# Do something while cell contains X and next cells are numbers

Tags: excel

I need to apply a discount to all products bought by a specific client, but all the data is in the same column.

I could do this if data was in different columns and duplicated, but I don't know how to proceed with data in the same column.

The data is displayed like:

```
Client:1
2341
56    
876
Client:2
234
3432
Client:1
23
7654
```

The numbers represent the item code they bought. I need something like

"if cell is client 1, while next cells are numbers apply this discount in another column of each cell with number".

It is a document of 500000 entries, so it's a bit hard to do it manually.

Comment: Power Query would be a good fit to try and solve this problem. What excel version do you have?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Excel 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps to do the first part of normalizing the data. Next would be to join the orders/products and the discounts.

In Excel:

1- Add header

2-Convert to table

3- Get data from table

In Power Query:

1- Add a custom column to extract the orders/products

Column name: Order

```
try Number.From([Data]) otherwise null
```

2- Add a custom column to extract the clients

Column name: Client

```
if [Order] = null then [Data] else null
```

3- Fill down the Client column

4- Remove nulls from Order column

5- Extract Client numbers with "Extract text after delimiter"

6- Remove the Data column

7- Reorder the columns

See the screen cast:

[image]

If this helps, remember to mark the answer to help others...

Comment: Gracias Ricardo. This is way beyond my knowledge, but totally worked. I'll save this gif for later cases. Thank you a lot!